# SQL Query - Find records with field that has cardinality greater than one

Tags: sql

I've got a list of records in a table with usernames and school terms.  I'd like to find all usernames which have more than one unique school term listed for them in the table overall.  So if I had:

```
Username      Term
-------------------
tester1       19/FA
tester1       19/SP
tester2       19/FA
```

I would only want to select tester1, since it has more than one term present for that username in the table.

Seems like this should be a pretty simple SQL query, but I'm not able to use any grouping statements to make it work.

Comment: What do you mean by "not able"? Is there any restriction on using `GROUP BY`?

Comment: What does "I'm not able to use any grouping statements* mean?

Comment: I just meant I tried grouping the result set but wasn't able to get the answer I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `group by` with a having clause:

```
select username
from t
group by username
having min(term) <> max(term);
```

If you want all the rows, then use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by username) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Or exists:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.username = t.username and t2.term <> t.term);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `HAVING` to filter out rows:

```
select username
from t
group by username
having count(distinct term) > 1
```

If your assignment does not allow you to use `GROUP BY` you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to filter out rows. For example:

```
select username
from (
  select 
    username,
    row_number() over(partition by username order by term) as rn
  from t
  ) x
where rn = 2
```

Comment: Thanks, your first suggestion worked fine.  Don't know why I didn't think of using HAVING, probably because I need it so rarely.